# Do the general population of the Galaxy know the Skywalker family tree?

Tags: star-wars, luke-skywalker, kylo-ren, princess-leia

Does someone like Poe Dameron, a member of the armed forces and citizen of the galaxy (i.e. not an insider per se), know that Kylo Ren, who captures and tortures him, is the son of his General?

Do other planets learn that Princess Leia of Alderaan's biological father gave the order to blow up her planet?

Are these things known to the general population of the galaxy, or are they kept quiet like the Skywalker twins were kept secret in the past?

Comment: I think this question is asking about extended family. Not just Ma and Pa

Comment: I think the answers to the other question tell us which individuals know about Kylo Ren’s parentage, rather than answering the question about general awareness of Skywalker parentage. However, as Darth Vader didn’t seem to know that Leia was his daughter, it’s unlikely anyone else does; and the other question’s answers do say that it was forbidden to mention Kylo Ren’s parentage, so presumably that’s being kept fairly quiet.

Comment: Please stop adding "not a duplicate" to the title.